# trouble using Fast Application Switching

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using from codeplex Tombstone Helper ([Tombstone Helper](http://tombstonehelper.codeplex.com/)) and am having problems fast switching between apps.

I've included the "two line code" method and am testing my app in the emulator.

I've activated the tombstoning option for debugging. all my controls have names; i then press the 'home' button and when i go back to my app i still see the "Resuming" loading message. I have in my App.xaml.cs a bool to see if my app was dormant or tombstoned :

```
WasTombstoned = !e.IsApplicationInstancePreserved;
```

and in my xaml view page i have :

```
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)       

    {            
if(App.WasTombstoned == true)         
         this.RestoreState();

    }

    protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e) 
  {   
   this.SaveState(e);    
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but have you set the project to build against version 7.1?

Comment: @calum I don't think IsApplicationInstancePreserved would've let him compile against 7.0

Comment: @willmel good point - I think I must have had a caffeine deficiency when I posted that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Resuming..." message is displayed by the OS while restoring an application which has been tombstoned. If you configure your project to show this while debugging this is expected.

If you see the phone (or emulator) seemingly hang indefinitely on this message during debugging then that's due to the process the debugger having been unloaded from memory. If you press F5 or equivalent in VisualStudio this will resume the process where you were and you can continue debugging.

Or is your question really something else?
Do you still see the same behaviour if you comment out the call to `RestoreState()`?

Comment: i wish to be able to have the "Fast Application Switching"(FAS) enabled. From what i understood, FAS avoids "Resuming..." screen and restores the view more quickly.

Comment: the question is, why am i still seing the "Resuming" screen although i'm detecting if the application is tombstoned or dormant (which works well) and then try to restore it using Tombstone Helper?

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru so you're saying that the call to `RestoreState()` changes the behaviour in this area. Is that right?

Comment: i personally think that SaveState and RestoreState are not working, so the i have nothing to "Fast Restore"

Comment: Note that the library doesn't have any specific handling for FAS but requires you to only call RestoreState when you are restoring from tombstoning, not a FAS. Can you share a repro for what you're seeing. Please also note that the "Resuming..." message is displayed by the OS before the app is restored and the code in the OnNavigatedTo handler is called.

Comment: the problem is that the Tombstone Helper is not saving my data.. If i restore my app after tombstoning, the data isn't reloaded, it's just an empty page

Comment: That sounds like 2 separate issues. Have you got a repro for the basic functionality not working?

Comment: could it be a problem that my StackPanels are added in code and not xaml ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5091/discussion-between-matt-lacey-and-badescu-alexandru)

Answer (score 0):

There's a checkbox in the application properties Debug tab which tells the emulator whether to tombstone or not when debugging so that you can easily test your tombstoning code. This is probably currently set to tombstone. A bit more detail on the subject:

http://windowsphonerocks.com/Developer/DeveloperArticles/tabid/64/Article/163/how-to-enable-windows-phone-application-tombstone-in-emulator-when-debugging.aspx

Comment: yes, i know this.. "am testing my app in the emulator.I've activated the tombstoning option for debugging". i mentioned it in my post. please read the question again.

Comment: the question is, why am i still seing the "Resuming" screen although i'm detecting if the application is tombstoned or dormant (which works well) and then try to restore it using Tombstone Helper?

Comment: Why wouldn't you see the Resuming screen if you have the emulator set with tomstoning turned on? Seems like that is the correct behavior.